# Contar etiquetas XML

Tags: xml, xpath

Como podría saber el numero de etiquetas del fichero XML que contienen una cadena especifica. Tengo el siguiente XML, necesito saber el numero total de etiquetas que contienen la cadena 'OK' con Xpath.

El número de etiquetas puede variar.
He probado con la función `count(/estados/Result/text() = 'OK')` y `count(/estados/Result/text()) = 'OK'` pero no se que forma más probar.

```
<estados>
  <Result>KO</Result>
  <Result>OK</Result>
  <Result>OK</Result>
  <Result>KO</Result>
</estados>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
count(/estados/Result[text() = 'OK'])
```

Faltaban los `[]`